# Set two images in single background image with nice alignment?

Tags: html, css

How to set two images in single background-image?  I have two pictures but there is an issue with separating this two (one is overlying on another).

Below is my style for that div.

```
.layout_core_menu_logo {
    padding: 20px 0 0px 0;
    background: url(~/application/xxx.gif) transparent no-repeat top;
    background-size: 968px 200px;
    a { 
        background: url("/application/xx1.gif?c=573") no-repeat,url("/application/themes/xx2.gif")no-repeat;
        width:1160px;
        height: 187px;
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        position: relative; top: 20px; left: 0px;    
    }
}
```

Comment: fix the layout, it is hard to read

Comment: also did you try to use background-position ?

Comment: a { background: url("/application/themes/epatients/images/coa/title_ortho.gif?c=573") no-repeat,url("/application/themes/epatients/images/coa/title_ca.gif")no-repeat;
    width:1160px;
    height: 187px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: relative; top: 20px; left: 0px;    
} problem with  this part

Comment: obviously problem.... you are closing the bracket for `.layout_core_menu_logo` after you close it for `a`.  Why don't you separate them?

Comment: thank you for quick response i did it with following correction in my code ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style>
   a { 
       background:url("/application/xx1.gif?c=573&c=573") no-repeat scroll 51% 60%, 
       url("/application/xx2.gif?c=573") no-repeat scroll 0% 20% transparent ;
   }
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the position and background size of each image.

```
 .layout_core_menu_logo {
   padding: 20px 0 0px 0;
   background: url(http://www.mvploops.com/files/_willow/categories/281_Sample-    Packs.jpg) transparent no-repeat top;
   background-size:100% 100%; 
  }
  a { 
    background: url("http://www.detailinggurus.com/images/sample_bottles.jpg") no-repeat top left,url("http://www.mclub.com.ua/images/alb/cover42163_148565.jpg")no-repeat top right;
    background-size:50% 100%, 50% 100%;
    width:968px;
    height: 187px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    position: relative; top: 20px; left: 0px;    
 }
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/jmZ3p/)